# I want to keep spacing between the UILables in landscape mode

Tags: uiscrollview, landscape, spacing, perspective, portrait

I want to keep spacing between the UILables in my Xcode project when i'm in landscape mode.
I have a scrollview with a few labels on it & it looks good in portrait mode but when im in landscape mode the labels are rising over each other & it looks bad.
Is there any way to keep perspectivlly the spaces between the labels on landscape?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try playing with autoresizing masks on the labels. If that doesn't work just reposition the labels from the viewcontroller whenever you get the rotation events.